# Изображения и разбиение на слои

Tags: python, изображения

Добрый день! Не могли бы вы подсказать, какие библиотеки и модули нужно подключить, чтобы можно было работать с изображением и разбивать его на слои( или на теневые изображения попиксельно)?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что [PIL ImageChops](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm), то что нужно.